# Locate the Containing Package or Module **Before** Importing

Tags: python, vim, import

I often find myself needing to import something, but not quite sure of its fully qualified name. I usually end up opening a browser, performing an internet search like `python [target_of_import]`, and scanning a page or two until I find it.

This works, but causes a relatively long break in my workflow, especially if I have to search for a few in a row. How do other people address this?

Is there something like Haskell's [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) for Python?

[Note: I currently use `vim`, in case anyone suggests an IDE-based solution.]

**EDIT:** For answers concerning autocomplete, please specify this. In general, autocomplete is probably a non-starter solution since in the particular case I am asking about the leftmost characters of the string to be autocompleted are not known.

**EDIT 2:** While I will not categorically rule out suggestions concerning switching to/learning a new IDE, I'm pretty unlikely to completely change the way I work to accomplish this (e.g., switching from `vim` on the command line to something like Eclipse + plugins).

Comment: In iPython I type in a few characters and hit tab.  I'm sure some IDEs offer similar autocompletion abilities. (I realize that's only useful if you know what the package/module starts with)

Comment: @roippi I'm not sure I understand how that could help. Let's say I want the fully-qualified name for `os.path.basename` and all I know is `basename` -- what do I start typing?

Comment: You can use pycharm IDE. It automatically lists out the packages on typing

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal Is it significantly different from autocomplete? E.g., would it answer my previous comment?

Comment: Eclipse & pydev together provide something akin to this.  If I type in `basename` and hit `ctrl + 1` I get a list of potential locations to import from.

Comment: @g.d.d.c While I'm not averse to switching to/learning a new IDE for this, downloading the Java runtime and using Eclipse is probably where I'll draw the line. :)

Comment: No worries, just thought I'd throw it out there in case you already used eclipse for other things.  I've become quite fond of pydev and its features.

Comment: there are two questions: 1. how to guess the package name (possible answers: use google or hoogle analogs for Python)? 2. how to integrate it with `vim` (e.g., run a script on a keystroke)? The first question has no single answer e.g., what package do you want to import for `load` function? The second question should be easy to answer if you know how to answer the first

Comment: The second question you're asking about is not one I'm intending to ask. I mentioned my current IDE for clarifactory purposes since I knew in advance many people would suggest what their favorite IDE does in this situation, and that allows them to target their solution at me. The first question is the only one I'm really interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in vim using the [Unite.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim)

Enable fuzzy file searching by adding the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
call unite#filters#matcher_default#use(['matcher_fuzzy'])
```

Search for file:

```
:UniteWithInput file_rec/async:/base/path:!<cr>
```

Search within files:

```
:UniteWithInut grep:/base/path<cr>
```

Search file names and within files

```
:UniteWithInput file_rec/async:/base/path:! grep:/base/path<cr>
```

(Use  to change between sources)

See also `:h :UniteWithCursorWord`

This will open a buffer with the file matches. You can open the file by pressing enter but since you only want copy the file name simply use `y$` to yank the line, `q` to close the buffer and the `p` to paste the yanked line.

Comment: Please do correct me if I'm wrong, but this won't search within files, right? That's only a partial solution since this would locate modules but not, say, functions or classes within modules. Not to mention, I really just want the path information. More rarely opening the source code is what I want; the rest of the time it is overkill.

Comment: Unite allows you to include results from multiple different sources, the grep source will allow you to search with files. It can be a bit hard getting set up with unite but its great once you've figured it out.

Comment: All right. I give in. You've piqued my interest! I'll add this to my project list since it requires quite a bit of configuration (blergh).